# PayPal sandbox works, production does not work. Can anybody provide a solution?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, payment-processing

I've integrated paypal payment in my online store.

When in sandbox mode and using a sandbox paypal account to make a payment, everything works.

When in production mode and using a REAL paypal account to make a payment, the user receives this error on paypal checkout page:

[image: paypal error]

When I try to pay with the same real paypal account on another online store that uses the same paypal method for receiving payments, everything works.

I redirect users to paypal checkout with this code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="here I insert our business email" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="8514" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="here I insert customer email" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.ourdomain.com/success.php?orderid=210141&h=03e2f8258d" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.ourdomain.com/cancel.php?orderid=210141&h=03e2f8258d" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://www.ourdomain.com/update_paypal.php?orderid=210141&h=03e2f8258d" />
<button class="btn rightSignBig black" type="submit"><span><em>Pay with paypal</em></span></button>
</form>
```

What should I do to be able to receive payments on my business account in production?

Answer (score 1):

The LIVE transactions are being declined by PayPal, for business reasons. For certain **types of businesses**, credit card companies need certain agreements on file in order to process transactions.

So, the owner of the LIVE PayPal business account needs to contact PayPal's general business support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us and explain that all customer credit card transactions are being declined due to **the type of business**, and ask what they can do to resolve the issue.